# Extracting specific pattern of string using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a text while which shows certain output in the form of strings and numbers and from that I have a specific piece of text as follows .I want to extract a certain piece of text from that

This is a small piece of my content

```
gjhsgdjhgfjhdgfjkhsdgfjkhgsdfk7868736876534
Pattern is:
(4,24,[5,96]) -> (1,14,[14,15]), that is: "Poland" -> "Poland"
(4,46,[36,39]) -> (1,14,[14,15]), that is: "Kim" -> "Kim"

fhafsdhjdfgjhdagfkhj66876493985694(hjiikfghkjfhg,98698)
(hhgjhgdfj,jhgkjdhgf)
```

From this I want to get the output as

```
"Poland" -> "Poland"
"Kim" -> "Kim"
"The police" -> "The city police on Friday"
```

The code I tried is

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(Pattern is:)\\((.*?)\\)");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

  while(m.find())
  {
      System.out.println("fhkjsdfhkjsdh");
      System.out.println(m.group(2));

  }
```

Comment: @user3580294 "Pattern is:" is the piece of text I want to extract..My text file contains the word"Pattern is" and I want to extract the content after that

Comment: Where did `on   Friday` go?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov sry my mistake. I had editted my ques

Comment: Is your input spanning in multiple lines as shown?

Comment: @chopu Ah, must have missed that earlier. My mistake.

Comment: @anubhava yes my output is shown in multiple lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]+\"\\s*->\\s*\"[^\"]+\"");
```

Use the overall match.

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/qM6oQ7)

The expression just checks for strings of the form `"Poland" -> "Poland"` without bothering to check that `Pattern is` is matched anywhere, because (i) in the input that does not seem needed, and (ii) it is unclear what would constitute an ending delimiter of a Pattern section.

Let us know if this does what you want.

Comment: Glad it works chopu, thanks for letting me know. By the way this is not hwnd, though I'm sure he would have produced a great answer. :)

Comment: oh sry zx81 ..my mistake

Comment: @chopu no worries, it's a compliment. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
String newStr = str.replaceAll("^.*:", "");
System.out.println(newStr);
```

Comment: thank you for answering and giving attention to my question. But it's not the output I needed